# prove 2 ideal has the same monic generator

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me with this problem. I try many ways to solve this but still can't find the solution.Thanks

> Let $K$ be a subfield of field $F$, and suppose $f$, $g$ are polynomials in $K[x]$. Let $M_k$ be the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ in $K[x]$ and $M_f$ be the ideal they generate in $F[x]$.Show that $M_k$ and $M_f$ have the same monic generator

Comment: Hint: Go back to where you proved that $L[x]$ is a PID if $L$ is a field, and see how exactly you constructed the polynomial.

Comment: Can you clarify more? What does PID mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal $M_f$ is generated by some greatest common divisor $\gcd(f,g)$ of $f$ and $g$ in $F[x]$ . But if you look at the algorithm for computing the $\gcd(f,g)$ you will find that only the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are used in the calculations. In particular, if $f$ and $g$ lie in $K[x]$ then the same holds for $\gcd(f,g)$.